# JavaScript instant CSS Animation with Style assignment

Tags: javascript, css, animation, styles, instant

My Problem is, that I want to do simple CSS Animations with the Help of JavaScript. There is already a Solution that I know, but I am trying to figure out a Way to simplify the Process.

Example:

```
<span id="span">Hello World</span>
<script>
var span;
goRed();
function goRed()
{
    span = document.getElementById("span");
    span.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-transition-duration:1s");
    span.style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

When I run this Example, the Hello World becomes instantly red.

So far i solved this Problem by doing the following in the Function goRed():

```
window.setTimeout('span.style.color = "red";', 0);
```

A delayed Change of the Color works.

Want I do not want to do is to assign the transition-duration in the Stylesheet before, because I want to create an API to do simple CSS Animations.

So is a there a more elegant Way to do this?

Thanks in advance